# Правильное оформление списков

Tags: другое

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если после предложения, заканчивающегося двоеточием, идет нумерованный список с цифрами (или буквами), то предложения в этом списке пишутся с большой или с маленькой буквы? Про маркированный список знаю, что со строчной... 
Напр.

Xxxxxx:

1. xxxxx;
2. xxxxx;
3. xxxxx.

Или по-другому?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С прописной буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует цифра с точкой или прописная буква с точкой.

1. Язык.
2. Речь.

А. Язык.
Б. Ре***чь.
Со строчной буквы начинается текст каждого элемента в перечне, если ему предшествует цифра со скобкой:***
1) новое и старое;
2) старое и новое.
***Аналогичным образом оформляются перечни, элементы которых начинаются строчной буквой со скобкой:***

***а) новое и старое;
б) старое и новое.***

```
Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2013. С. 282–286.
А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова. Справочник издателя и автора. 2-е изд., М., 2003. С. 38–44.
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.