# Оформление перечня, содержащего вопросительные предложения

Tags: пунктуация, перечисление

> К работе с клиентом можно подготовиться заранее. Обычно они приходят с тремя вопросами:
>
> Что именно входит в комплекс услуг?
>
> Какие есть способы оплаты?
>
> Предоставляется ли гарантия?

Правильно ли оформлен перечень, содержащий в качестве элементов вопросительные предложения?

Comment: После "ромбов" нужны пробелы и местоимение нужно согласовать, как указано в ответах. Остальное всё допустимо.

Comment: Подобный вопрос уже был задан: [Оформление перечня и инфинитивное предложение](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/437068/%d0%9e%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: См также: [Правильное оформление списков](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/40395/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Я привёл в своём ответе пример из авторитетного источника. Очевидно, вопросительные знаки имеют не меньше прав, чем точки.

Comment: @М_Г Не думаю, что мой текущий вопрос сильно похож на те, что вы указали. Речь о вопросительных предложениях в качестве элементов перечня.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко . Не думаю, что тип предложения что-то меняет.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, такой способ оформления перечня (двоеточие, а затем каждый пункт как отдельное предложение) допустим, только по стандарту идет тире и пробел, а не ромб (впрочем, это не совсем так, смотри дополнения), а тот факт, что предложения вопросительные, сути дела не меняет. Вы можете поискать подобные вопросы на этом сайте, а я постараюсь дополнить мой ответ позже.

Местоимение нужно поставить в том же числе, что и существительное, но вариант "oбычно он приходит" мне не нравится. Остается сочетать "к работе с клиентами" с "oбычно они приходят" либо "к работе с клиентом" с "oбычно клиенты приходят".

Не вижу проблем с тем, что используется слово *вопросы* и называется конкретное числе вопросов.

Дополнение 1. [Здесь](https://infogra.ru/typography/11-pravil-oformleniya-spiskov-i-perechnej) указано, что текст после тире не может начинаться с прописной, поэтому вам лучше использовать цифры с последующей точкой, тем более что названо число вопросов:

К работе с клиентом можно подготовиться заранее. Обычно клиенты приходят с тремя вопросами:

1. Что именно входит в комплекс услуг?
2. Какие есть способы оплаты?
3. Предоставляется ли гарантия?

Подобный пример оформления списка есть у [Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=87,8#pp87):

> § 83. Пишутся слитно:
>   1. Наречия, образованные соединением предлогов с наречиями… навряд ли, задаром. <…>
>   2. Наречия, образованные соединением предлогов в и на с собирательными числительными… натрое, но: по двое, по трое.
>   3. Наречия, образованные соединением предлогов с краткими прилагательными… потихоньку, сгоряча.

Дополнение 2. Я нашел У Мильчина ([Перечни](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=N2p6GFY7PXkC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=df6F1BuSNA&sig=ACfU3U3M_PqdomKv-kjQSuYVphh8INRhMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5puzUp4TgAhXl2OAKHQtuAzYQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false)) в пункте п. 2.1.2. Б:

> знак тире (кружок, ромбик и т. п.)

Таким образом, Мильчин приравнивает ромбик к знаку тире, и в его примерах текст после тире  начинается со **строчной**.

А в [п. 2.5. Рекомендуемое употребление прописных букв](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=N2p6GFY7PXkC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&source=bl&ots=df6F1BuSNA&sig=ACfU3U3M_PqdomKv-kjQSuYVphh8INRhMA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj5puzUp4TgAhXl2OAKHQtuAzYQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%20%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F&f=false) Мильчин приводит только три случая:
а) текст элемента делится на предложения, разделенные точкой;
б) элемент обозначен номером-цифрой или прописной буквой с точкой;
б) элемент обозначен номером-цифрой или строчно буквой с закрывающей скобкой, но содержит много слов и сложен по структуре, а способ обозначения с цифром или буквой с точкой уже использован для элементов старшего перечня.

Дополнение 3. Вопреки всему сказанному выше о ромбиках, тот же Мильчин на стр. 439 приводит пример, в котором стоят прописные буквы после ромбиков как графических символов (см. ответ grizzly). Прав он или нет — не мне судить.

Comment: *по стандарту идет тире и пробел, а не ромб* — очень часто в книге выделяют ромбами и другими знаками. В справочнике Мильчина (его можно считать стандартом) такое выделение абзацев — элементов перечня называется "графическим", и в качестве примера там приводится именно ромб (только с пробелом после него, конечно).

Comment: @grizzly, Допустим,  с ромбом Мильчин пошел дальше Лопатина и Розенталя, но они также пишут, что начинать с прописной можно только после точки, а точка после ромба не ставится. А что у Мильчина?

Comment: А при чём здесь Лопатин и Розенталь?! Вы точно понимаете, чем издательские стандарты отличаются от грамматических правил? У Мильчина сказано так: "10. Графический способ выделения абзацев — элементов перечня применяется тогда, когда нужно <...> или когда нет нужды подчеркивать порядок элементов перечня, а требуется лишь отчетливо выделить каждый элемент". И приведен пример с точно таким оформлением, как у автора вопроса.

Comment: @grizzly, Я нашел у Мильчина п. 2.1.2. Б (ссылка дана в дополнении к ответу) . Я понимаю так, что текст после ромбика должен начинаться с **прописной**. А Вы что нашли?

Comment: Прописная или строчная зависит от того, где использован графический знак. У меня "Справочная книга корректора и редактора", которую я цитировал выше. (Я не нашёл этого в гугло-книгах, но это не лишает меня права на неё ссылаться.) Я уже объяснял выше, что там дан точно такой пример оформления (среди многих других), как у автора вопроса.

Comment: М_Г Проверьте, правильно ли Вы употребляете слова "прописная" и "строчная"? Создаётся впечатление, что Вы инвертировали эти понятия. Впрочем, не важно. Всё равно Вы ссылаетесь на какой-то другой случай, который Вам попался на глаза. Если Вы найдёте страницу 439 справочника, на который Вы ссылаетесь, то найдёте там нужный случай.

Comment: @grizzly, Я дополнил ответ еще одной цитатой из Мильчина. Возможно, правила оформления текстов не такие строгие, если в разных изданиях того же автора приводятся разные примеры.

Comment: @grizzly, Увы, страницу 439 Гугл не показывает.

Comment: Я привёл фотокопию страницы в своём ответе. Не могу больше спорить. Ставлю пока Вам минус, если отредактируете ответ, тогда сниму или заменю на плюс.

Comment: @grizzly, Если Мильчин противиречит самому себе, то поставьте ему минус, а мне-то за что? Ну хорошо, для полноты картины я могу добавить еще одну опцию со ссылкой на Ваш ответ.

Comment: Он не противоречит. Нигде не сказано, что такое оформление запрещено, а примеры, на которые Вы сослались, относились к вложенным элементам многоуровневых перечней. Ладно, я минус снял — не хочу обострять отношения и, вообще, атмосферу на сайте.

Comment: Про знаки препинания после абзацев – элементов перечня: «…Точку, если элементы обозначены номером-цифрой с точкой, прописной буквой с точкой, а также номером-цифрой с закрывающей скобкой, строчной буквой с закрывающей скобкой, _наборным знаком, но начинаются с прописной буквы_, т. е. точке после обозначения элемента или прописной букве в начале элемента (но не потому, что первое слово - имя собственное) соответствует точка в конце элемента». Получается, после ромба элемент может начинаться с прописной.

Comment: https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091338.html#id-2Перечни-25Рекомендуемоеупотреблениепрописныхбукв

Answer (score 1):

Расширенный комментарий.

По просьбе М_Г прилагаю фотокопию 439 страницы "Справочника издателя и автора" Мильчина и Чельцовой. Текст на этой странице не имеет значения, она даётся только для подтверждения возможности графического оформления элементов перечня "ромбиками".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Несовпадение числа — «с клиентом» и «они» — надо бы избежать, а также избавится от слова *вопросы*. Количества вопросов лучше не называть: нумерации в вашем тексте нет, и это правильно. Позиции следует формулировать однотипно; после начального символа в строке следует давать пробел.

```
К работе с клиентами можно подготовиться заранее, имея ввиду самую важную для них информацию:

 о комплексе услуг,

 о способах оплаты,

 о предоставлении гарантий.
```

Comment: Согласитесь, что после каждого элемента перечня в Вашем случае нужно поставить точку с запятой.

Comment: https://infogra.ru/typography/11-pravil-oformleniya-spiskov-i-perechnej ===== Здесь есть Правила оформления списков и перечней. Одно из них (пример 5): «Если части перечня состоят из простых словосочетаний или одного слова, они отделяются друг от друга запятыми. Если же части перечня усложнены (внутри них есть запятые), их лучше отделять точкой с запятой. Пример 3 из этих Правил показывает пунктуацию для третьего уровня нумерации.

Comment: Да, я посмотрел, что уже в издании 1999 г. приведены такие же правила. До этого я ориентировался на старое издание, где ограничение было не более двух слов в перечне. Согласен с Вами.

Comment: Почему нужно избавиться от слова «вопросы»? Оно прекрасно предваряет перечень.

Comment: От него надо избавиться, т. к. в перечне строчки и так заканчивались знаками: вопросы называть словом — излишество. То же самое (зеркально) можно сказать и о вопросительных знаках: их можно не ставить после обобщающего слова.